# SharePoint 2013 central administration not displaying correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

My sp2013 central admin site appears as the images shown above. No css, javascript, or images work. What should I check to determine the issue? I have seen in the forums that some say it's a permissions issue or check the ULS logs. I have checked the logs but I see no errors regarding loading images or javascript. Some mention an IE browser issue. Our IE settings are controlled by GPO.

[image: sharepoint 2013 central administration]

Comment: have you tried to clear the browser cache? also reset IIS on the central admin server?

Comment: Try to Run SP Config Wizard

Comment: reprovision the central admin may fix the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try hold the Control key while pressing F5. This looks like an issue with the style sheet used by your browser, and Ctrl-F5 will force a refresh of all the files used to service this request, overwriting any potential corruption in your cache.

Comment: I have tried cntrl-f5 and that doesn't work. I have tried this in IE 9.0 and IE 11.0

Comment: Have you tried from multiple machines and different accounts?

Comment: I tried from some different workstations and I get the same thing. I did however use f12 in IE checked css. CSS tried loading but failed. Javascript errors because  the js functions are undefined.

Comment: So... What changes have been made to the system recently? Do the JavaScript files still exist on the server?

Comment: Question
You cannot vote on your own post
0
I solved this issue. In trying to access other sites on this same development server I was getting 500 internal server error and 404 errors. I was specifically getting internal server errror 500.19 which complained about something wrong in the web.config file in c:\programs files\common files\microsoft shared\web servers extensions\template\layouts. So I copied a web.config from production to test and the central admin page now displays correctly and my other web sites display correctly too. Thanks for all the suggestions.